# Javascript code for a combo box that depends on another combo box

Tags: javascript, pdf, combobox

I am creating a PDF fillable form and I would like to create 2 combo boxes named "Primary" and "Secondary".

The values for "Primary" can be "Fuel" or "Rail". So far I have succeeded in this.

However, I want that if the user selects "Fuel" in the "Primary" I want the "Secondary"to list the values "Locomotive" and "Misc". And if the user selects "Rail" in "Primary" I want the "Secondary" to list the values "MRO" or "Snow Removal". The user can select then whatever values they want from the list generated in the "Secondary" combo box.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use onchange().
On chance read the value of primary,  clean and fill secondary.  Simple!

Comment: Thank you gillall! Do you mind writing the code? Because I have 0 knowledge in Javascript. Thank you again for your help!